# Chance of not finding an alternating Hamiltonian path in a colored graph in $n$ random walks

Tags: probability, graph-theory, random-walk, hamiltonian-path

## Introduction

Given a random graph which can be constructed as follows:

generate $s$ pairs of unconnected **black** edges and $2 \cdot s$ vertices

connect these **black** edges using **red** edges, where the average number of **red** edges on a vertex is $a$

## Question

What is the chance that, starting from a given vertex and following a random walk of **alternating** **black** and **red** edges that one doesn't end up with a Hamiltonian path in $n$ tries (in terms of $n$, $s$ and $a$). Or a good upperbound

Also is there a difference between this chance for a given $s$ and a graph with $s+k\text{ }$  **black** edges where one starts the walk with $k$ black edges already visited

**Example:**

[image: m]

a graph where $s = 3$ and $a = 2$